# How to use Max/Min Range filter with Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel-nova

I'm building an admin portal with a requirement to filter by max/min in multiple columns (price, rate...etc)

I wasn't able to find a built-in range filter and https://github.com/dcasia/nova-slider-filter is not compatible with Nova 4

any suggestion for a plugin or way to get range filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nova 4 have built in function just any Numeric field call **->filterable()**

it will show like this

[image]